# Does it matter if I use new to initialize a defstruct in maxima?

Tags: maxima

Initializing a defstruct using new or without new, seems to do the same, is there any difference?

```
(%i1) defstruct(foo(a,b));
(%o1)                             [foo(a, b)]
(%i2) f: foo(1,2);
(%o2)                          foo(a = 1, b = 2)
(%i3) f@a;
(%o3)                                  1
(%i4) f_new: new(foo(1,2));
(%o4)                          foo(a = 1, b = 2)
(%i5) f_new@a;
(%o5)                                  1
(%i6)
```

Without using new, the code seems a bit shorter and easier, but I'm not sure if some code will break if I use this pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both ways are OK. The only difference so far as I know is that `new(foo(...))` will ensure that there are the correct number of initial values. For example `new(foo(1))` and `new(foo(1, 2, 3))` will give errors, with `foo` as defined above. Just writing `foo(1)` or `foo(1, 2, 3)` doesn't trigger an error (maybe it should).